# Calling `format.js` results in "No template found" Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to offer my users a link to click which will: (1) trigger an AJAX call, (2) activate a controller/action which will destroy a `Comment` object, (3) have that same controller/action respond back with *both* HTML and JavaScript.

Everything works fine, except the JavaScript response. For some reason, Rails cannot find the `.js.erb` template that corresponds to my controller/action, so it doesn't fire any client-side JavaScript, and instead throws a "No template found" warning.

View that contains the clickable link:

```
<%= link_to blog_post_comment_path(@blog_post,c), method: :delete, :remote => true do %>
  <%= fa_icon "trash" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @blog_post = BlogPost.find(params[:blog_post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.delete
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_blog_post_path(@blog_post), notice: "Comment deleted!" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I have a view that lives at: `/app/views/comments/destroy.js.erb`. No matter what JavaScript I add to this file, it won't execute.

When I click the `link_to` link in a browser, the Rails logs shows:

```
Comment Destroy (1.5ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 44]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7
No template found for CommentsController#destroy, rendering head :no_content
```

Comment: What happens if you put the js before the html in the respond_to?

Comment: @Doughtz: Switching the order of the `format.html` and `format.js` calls results in the same warning: `No template found for CommentsController#destroy`.

Comment: What’s your routes file look like?

Comment: @Doughtz: My `routes.rb` file: https://gist.github.com/jonathancadepowers/b77af6f544602d0c4defcd44929d09ab

Comment: Do you have `jquery-ujs` or `rails-ujs` set up, in your gemfile or javascript files?